# Why am I unable to RDP to Windows 10 since virtualizing it?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, remote-desktop, remotefx

This could also be related to a recent windows update.  I recently updated to 2004 to be able to run WSL2.  When I virtualized the machine I followed the [recommended Oracle Virtual box steps](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows), which included running a script to remove the disk adapter drivers. then I imaged the disk over to a VMDK.  Everything on the machine runs fine, there are the occasional bugs, that don't seem related to this.

When I RDP in I get the error message below.

I have found several error messages in the Event Viewer on the Remote Machine.  All of the interesting ones seem to be under RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS.  Here are some of the more interesting ones in order.

1. 'Failed GetConnectionProperty' in CUMRDPConnection::QueryProperty at 3344 err=[0x80004001]
2. 'Connection doesn't support logon error redirector' in CUMRDPConnection::GetLogonErrorRedirector at 4657 err=[0x80004001]
3. 'Failed GetConnectionProperty' in CUMRDPConnection::QueryProperty at 3344 err=[0x80004001]
4. Disconnect trace:CUMRDPConnection Disconnect trace:'calling spGfxPlugin->PreDisconnect()' in CUMRDPConnection::PreDisconnect at 5073 err=[0x12], Error code:0x12
5. TCP socket WRITE operation failed, error 64
6. TCP socket READ operation failed, error 64

Here are some of the things I have attempted so far.

- Confirmed IP Address
- Disabled Firewall Attempted to disable RemoteFX
  via GPO https://serverfault.com/q/886027/95189 then
- attempted to
  disable it via Registry. Added and then removed

  - Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal
    Server\WinStations\fEnableRemoteFXAdvancedRemoteApp with 0x00000000
- Attempted to increase the Max Outstanding Connections

  - https://serverfault.com/a/940808/95189
- Changed RDP host hostname

  - Some research indicated something about cloning machines could confuse the
    network.
- Install VirtualBox Extension Pack

  - Running 6.1.6 on everything
  - 6.1.10 seems to be the latest via Oracle, but with the Ubuntu repos 6.1.6 seems to be what they have available.
- Disabled Nested VT-x/AMD-V

  - Something about RemoteFX requiring this feature, so I attempted to disable RemoteFX by
    removing its requirement.
- Disable URCP

  - https://itcalls.net/windows-10-version-1809-black-screen-when-connecting-rdp-to-server-2019/
- Attempt to update Hyper-V Virtual Machine Bus Provider but it failed.

[image: Screenshot of error message when using RDP to connect to remote windows machine]

Comment: Were you ever able to get this fixed?

Comment: No I was not able to.

Comment: That's too bad. My issue sounds similar... https://superuser.com/q/1598296/28834

Comment: I took a look at your first few lines... my issue isn't freezing, but rather wont connect at all.  Some of those error messages are similar though.  I might work on it again soon.  Thanks for reminding me, I'll ping your question if I make any headway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved for me:

The last thing I tried in VMware was a checkbox for that specific machine. "Accelerate 3D graphics" <- Uncheck this box.

This was a real computer that I virtualized.  Windows 10 (Guest)
Running on WMware Workstation 14 Pro.  The host computer is running windows 7

I have been down the path of everything you have already tried.  Wish I could restore every little change and just hit that box. Lost a day of work too.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like something I would do.  Not sure if I still have that VM around, even if, I am moved on to qemu.

Comment: Oh wait I was using virtual box. Even still I am pretty sure I would have clicked the accelerate 3d graphics.

Answer (score 0):

We noticed we had installed a VPN client on our Windows Server 2016 (Netmotion) which was also having a problem loading.  Uninstalled netmotion and problem solved.

but I had also applied the registry entry you mentioned above.

so which one fixed it?  don't know, but we can now RDP into our server.