# Remote connection to Windows 10 sometimes freezes

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I remotely connect using RDP from a Windows 8.1 computer to a Windows 10 Pro computer (version 2004, 19041.572) and am able to work just fine.

However, it occasionally freezes for a minute. This happens 1 to 5 times a day.

When looking in the Windows Event Viewer on the Windows 10 computer, one of the RDP logs (Microsoft-Windows-RemoteDesktopServices-RdpCoreTS/Operational) has errors recorded.

Here are some snippets from that log, with my comments:

*First log entry when the freeze happened…*

- TCP socket WRITE operation failed, error 10054
- RDP_TCP: An error was encountered when transitioning from StateUnknown in response to Event_Disconnect (error code 0x80072746).
- TCP socket READ operation failed, error 64
- TCP socket WRITE operation failed, error 64
- TCP socket WRITE operation failed, error 995
- Interface method called: OnDisconnected

*Lots of other Info entries, then:*

- Disconnect trace:CUMRDPConnection Disconnect trace:'calling spGfxPlugin->PreDisconnect()' in CUMRDPConnection::PreDisconnect at 5073 err=[0x80072746], Error code:0x80072746
- …
- The disconnect reason is 14
- …
- The network characteristics detection function has been disabled because of Reason Code: 2(Server Configuration).

*It automatically started to reconnect, then:*

- 'Failed GetConnectionProperty' in CUMRDPConnection::QueryProperty at 3344 err=[0x80004001]

*Continued to connect, then:*

- 'Failed CreateVirtualChannel call on this Connections Stack' in CUMRDPConnection::CreateVirtualChannel at 2958 err=[0xd0000001]

*Continued, but got two more of the above error.*

*Connection was reestablished and continued with no further log entries*

What is wrong and how can this be fixed?

Comment: A similar issue: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/9a0b1049-5211-49c9-91ef-82f94645ac04/windows-10-enterprise-virutal-machines-frequent-disconnects-due-to-remotefx-on-hyper-v?forum=winserverTS

Comment: Another: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/ffacf559-ba51-434a-9cc8-bb32546f6305/rdp-frequent-disconnects-windows-10-1607-and-server-2016-essentials-tcp-socket-write-operation?forum=winserverTS

Comment: From admin elevated cmd run `sfc /scannow`, let that complete then run `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`, now reboot and see if the problem still exists. Try on both the remote system and the Win 8 system to be thorough. What type of network adapter does the remote system and the Win 8 system use? Both Ethernet, one WiFi and the other Ethernet or what? Seems like network connection issue so check over network adapter settings and maybe disallow the OS from using power saving on all applicable network adapters.

Comment: The first error is WSAECONNRESET (10054) - "Connection reset by peer. A existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". This error occurs when the connection is *reset by the peer application*. The problem might therefore be on Windows 8.1 computer, do you see any error there in the Event Viewer or elsewhere?

Comment: @harrymc Thanks. When this happens, a different VPN from the host to a 3rd network is also dropped, which seems to indicate that the problem is local to the host. I can't reproduce the problem on demand, but 99% of the time it happens when a dialog box appears on the host.

Comment: What kind of dialog box?

Comment: Have you checked for updated network adapter drivers on the machine you use for all the connections? Does rebooting the wifi routers or home ISP routers help make the problem not appear as often once a reboot occurs? Network devices are vulnerable to fragmented memory so try rebooting all your switches, routers, firewall, etc. and see if that helps. If so, automate a routing power cycle during off hours e.g. 4 AM.

Comment: The dialog box has been a UAC Yes/No box, a Windows 10 notification toast, an Outlook new message box, and probably a few others. The drop has also happened with nothing showing - I'm typing and suddenly realize that I'm not seeing the last few letters that I typed.

Comment: How are you connected to the router, ethernet or wifi? Is Windows 8.1 fully patched (why not upgrade it to Windows 10)? Try: In `gpedit.msc` navigate to 
*Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Connections* and enable "Configure keep-alive connection interval" while keeping its value as "1".

Comment: @harrymc I've now rebuilt the client with Windows 10. We'll see if the problem persists.

Comment: Good. I have added it to my answer. Let me know if that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the client computer was rebuilt with Windows 10.  The problem has not been noticed in the day or two since.

Unfortunately, there's no way to know whether it was a Windows 8.1 issue, or a setting on the computer when it was running 8.1 that was impacting the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Those are network errors. You are unlikely to solve it by looking at Windows logs. You will need to troubleshoot the network connection all along the full path. If this includes the open internet you are going to have links that you can't see or fix.

I recommend using Wireshark on both ends and filter the traffic so you only see the RDP tunnel. This will give you an idea of where the connection is lost. Then you can check your networking hardware for events near the timestamps of the trouble seen in wireshark.

Comment: This is inside a VPN tunnel, so might be more possible to trace.

Comment: @GlenLittle Yes you could instrument both ends of the tunnel. As long as the tunnel itself stays up then you know it's somewhere else. If the tunnel itself also drops for a bit then you know the problem is in the internet or tunnel protocol itself.

Answer (score 0):

In response to a comment of mine, the poster has upgraded from Windows 8.1
to Windows 10. We will see if that has solved the problem.

---

Because of the dialog boxes, the idle time limit might be reached for the RDP session,
causing its termination.

The settings for session time limits may be found via `gpedit.msc`, at
*Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Session Time Limits*.

You may adjust here the four settings as desired.
You are probabaly mostly interested in
"Set time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop Services sessions" and
"Set time limit for active Remote Desktop Services sessions",
but check all of them.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this is related to a timeout. The "freeze" happens instantly when a dialog box shows up and I am actively using the session.

Comment: @GlenLittle: If the problem has not returned, please take care of your bounty before it disappears.

Comment: Sorry that you didn't get any of the bonus when it expired. Your question about upgrading nudged me to finally do the update. Unfortunately, the question I asked here never got resolved without reinstalling the OS (which is not a nice answer for anyone else who might have the same issue).